# jquery: animate background position without plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, background-position

**hey guys,**
I have no luck making a simple background image animation working without the background-position-plugin of protofunc().

I used the plugin before and everything worked fine. However since the 1.6 version of jQuery the plugin is broken and doesn't work anymore.

Is there any chance I can make an easy backgroundPosition Animation without this Plugin?

This is the code I'm using:

```
    //Comment form
$("#comment").focus(function() {
    $(this).css({"background-color":"#fff"});
    $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: '220% 16px'}, {
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'easeOutQuint',
        complete: function() { }
    });

});
```

Comment: Mixing % and px in the same position properties is not recommended. Anyways you will have to post more code, I'm not sure if your $(this) is referencing the right object or not, not sure if you have the jquery UI loaded in your page so you can reference the easing plugin, too many unknowns, so more code plz.

Comment: updated my question... #comment is a textarea with a background image applied. When focussing the textarea the image should animate to the right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Either revert back to a previous version of jQuery that worked, or set an actual `<img>`as the background and animate that.